# Is it grammatical to say "My favorite food is apples"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatical to say "My favorite food is apples"? If not, is there a similar language structure that begins with the words "My favorite food" that I could use to explain this? Perhaps it would be grammatical to say "My favorite foods are apples".

I do not want to use the word 'apple' in  the singular form, if possible. I want to use the word 'apples' in plural.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is correct to say that because your subject and the be-verb are in agreement.

Or you may use "the apple" to represent the whole kind of apples as shown in this sentence:

"My favorite food is the apple."

However, if you reverse the sentence starting with "apples", you will have to use "are" since your subject is now plural.

"Apples are my favorite food."

Comment: Yes, "the apple" works well. But personally I see little wrong with "My favourite food is apple" - though beyond linguistics I must say it seems an odd sort of remark to make. To begin with, what exactly do we mean by "favourite food"? "My favourite fruit is apple/the apple" makes a lot more sense. But how, philosophically, can we draw a comparison between, let's say, apple, pâté de campagne, and smoked halibut, and express them in order of preference.

Comment: Have you ever heard anyone say _"My favorite food is the apple."_???

Comment: @Lordology No I haven't. But that's because of the reasons I gave in my comment. It would not be as unexpected to hear someone say "My favourite fruit is the apple".

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is:  *My favorite food is apples.*  You can't use the plural form.

*Food* is singular.  It must be followed by 'is'.  You can only use *are* when you are talking about multiple foods.

*My favorite foods are X and Y.*

*My favorite food is X.*

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/my-favourite-food-is-are.2352662/

Answer (score -2):

My favorite food is apples.    (wrong)    the thing here is (favorite food)
My favorite food is the apple. (correct)  the thing here is (among all fruits apples is yours number one.

My favorite animal is dog.      (wrong)   this means you eat dog.
My favorite animal is the dog.  (correct) this means you you like dogs instead all the other animals.